# Return union query into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 different select statemnts that union the results and display the orders  like so.

```
lab_orders              MED111
lab_orders              MED262383
mg_orders               MED262383
mg_orders               UNT222
pcg_pharmacogenetics    MED262371
pcg_pharmacogenetics    UNT248234
well_wellness           UST601061
well_wellness           UNTAccession
well_wellness           UST333
```

Using this query.

```
select 'mg_orders',csv as csv1
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from mg_orders)) as t1
union
select 'lab_orders',csv as csv2
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from lab_orders)) as t2
union
select 'pcg_pharmacogenetics',csv as csv3
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from pcg_pharmacogenetics)) as t3
union
select 'well_wellness',csv as csv4
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from well_wellness)) as t4
```

What I want to do is return the result set in separate columns, I have tried the following but get "no column named csv2"

```
select csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4
from(
select 'mg_orders',csv as csv1
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from mg_orders)) as t1
union
select 'lab_orders',csv as csv2
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from lab_orders)) as t2
union
select 'pcg_pharmacogenetics',csv as csv3
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from pcg_pharmacogenetics)) as t3
union
select 'well_wellness',csv as csv4
from (select csv from csvdata where csv not in(select orderid from well_wellness)) as t4
) as t


   lab_orders       mg_orders     pcg_pharmacogenetics            
   MED111           MED262383     MED262371
   MED262383        UNT222        UNT248234
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the result set would look like.

Comment: I added what I want the results to look like at the bottom.

Comment: what happened to well_wellness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `union`, the column-names or aliases from the first query would be used for the result-set. In your case the result set would contain `mg_orders` and `csv1` as column headers.

I assume you are looking for a query similar to

```
select 
max(case when csv not in(select orderid from mg_orders) then csv end) as csv1,
max(case when csv not in(select orderid from lab_orders) then csv end) as csv2,
max(case when csv not in(select orderid from pcg_pharmacogenetics) then csv end) as csv3,
max(case when csv not in(select orderid from well_wellness) then csv end) as csv4
from csvdata
```

Comment: So could i alias the columns from the other result sets in the first query?

Comment: This works, had to take out the 'max' to display all the records. Thanks